# Angular 5 to PHP POST returns always 403

Tags: php, angular, post, pdo, http-status-code-403

I had a working version but after some changes (I've no clue what) it doesn't work anymore. Now I brought everything back to a very simple application to make sure nothing else is in it's way. Yes, I know this is bad practice code, but that doesn't matter I just want to know what is wrong with this.

Now my code, it's not everything but I think this is everything you need to get an idea what my code does.

**Angular:**

Form:

```
<form>
  <table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
          <input placeholder="Username" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" required>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input placeholder="Password" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="password" type="password" name="password" required>
      </td>
    </tr></table>
</form>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="loginUser()" class="btn btn-primary" color="primary">Login</button>
```

Component:

```
loginUser() : void {
    let result = this.LoginService.loginUser(this.username, this.password);
    if (result === false) {
      this.wrongLoginNotification = 'Je hebt de onjuiste inloggegevens gebruikt!';
    }
  }
```

Service:

```
  private loginUrl = 'http://www.url.nl/path/api/?login=true';


  loginUser(username: string, password: string): boolean {
    let auth = {username: username, password: password};
    let authJson = JSON.stringify(auth);

    this.http.post(this.loginUrl, authJson)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.router.navigate(["home"]);
          return true;
        },
        err => {
          return false;
        }
      );

    return false;
  }
```

**This posts to server:**

```
{password: "TEST", username: "TEST1"}
```

**PHP script is very easy and is nothing more then:**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$servername = ""; // Changed this of course ;-)
$username = ""; // Changed this of course ;-)
$password = ""; // Changed this of course ;-)
$dbName = ""; // Changed this of course ;-)
$conn = null;

try
{
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbName", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
  header("HTTP/1.1 404");
}

if (isset($_GET['login'])) {
  echo 'Test';
}
```

**Now the PHP api (on same domain/url) returns:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /myurl/api/
on this server.<br />
</p>
<p>Additionally, a 403 Forbidden
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

What have I tried?

- I did check the premissions on folders: 755, files: 644.
- GET is still working, POST not.
- Read several posts on StackOverflow. Did try several things with .htaccess file such as adding:

  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"

I'm also in contact with my hosting. Anyone has any suggestions? **I do see lots of questions posted on this subject and everyone has an other solution**. What is the best way to filter this and get to the right point? I'm now just trying things without following a list or something that maybe gets me to the solution.

Any help would be very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header needs to be called before any other output. So your try/catch block looks something like this:

```
try
{
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbName", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  header("HTTP/1.1 404");
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

EDIT:
Also try to remove authJSON and use auth instead. Just pass that JSON object directly.

Comment: Can you be a little bid more specific?

Comment: Edited answer for you :)

Comment: I think it doesn't get in that part. I changed it, but doesn't fix the issue. Beside that, that part should work as GET works (and there I get a JSON result from the database back). I removed that as that part works. The POST part doesn't.

Comment: Try to remove authJSON and use auth instead. Just pass that JSON object directly.

Comment: Whoah thanks! That works. I don't know why this now didn't work and did before? But anyway this works. Could you please update your post so I can accept it? :)